# Getting filepath of opened device

Tags: c, linux

Say i open up /dev/ttyUSB0. Now i want to use its file descriptor to get its filepath.

```
int myfd;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char linkname[256];
ssize_t r;

myfd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);
if(myfd<0){

    perror("open error");
    exit(1);
}

r = readlink("/proc/self/fd/myfd", linkname, sizeof(linkname)-1);

if(r<0){
    perror("lstat");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("%s\n", linkname);

close(myfd);

    return 0;
}
```

What i should be getting is /dev/ttyUSB0.. Am i doing it the wrong way?

Comment: What made you think there'd be a `myfd` file in that directory? Were you expecting C to magically interpolate that string?

Comment: Yeah my mistake there i got it working by using sprintf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the string `myfd` isn't in the /proc filesystem? I think the link is named numerically, so  you need the *value* of the variable `myfd` in the call to `readlink()`.

Comment: so instead of doing it this way readlink("/proc/self/fd/myfd", linkname, sizeof(linkname)-1); I will do it this way? readlink("/proc/self/fd/the file descriptor number here", linkname, sizeof(linkname)-1);

Comment: Yeah but how will i do that? how will i know the number of myfd?..can you show me an example?

Comment: readlink("/proc/self/fd/3", linkname, sizeof(linkname)-1);
this works but i don't know why.